# Visual Code Error: Debugger adapter process terminated. Please Help

Tags: mono, c#, dotnet

I've been using Visual Studio in Windows for a couple years now but just starting changing to Visual Code in Linux (Ubuntu 16).

I followed the installation instruction from the Microsoft dotnet page and even watched a video tutorial they had posted. Everything installed and seemed to work just fine. I created the sample hello world app and ran it in VS terminal and it ran okay with no errors.. But when I added a little more code just I went to debug, it gives me an error of ..

```
Error: Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly ..
```

I have the C# and all the other needed extensions installed along with mono etc..

Am I missing something?

I'm not sure what information to post about the error but the 
Extention Log Output says:

```
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500
```

and the OmniSharp Log says:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 11/18/2016, 1:14:40 AM
    Target: /home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp

OmniSharp server started wth Mono
    Path: /home/dany/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.5.2/bin/run
    PID: 15606

OmniSharp: -s /home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp --hostPID 15567 --stdio DotNet:enablePackageRestore=false --encoding utf-8
{"Event":"log","Body":{"LogLevel":"INFORMATION","Name":"OmniSharp.Startup","Message":"Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp' on host 15567."},"Seq":1,"Type":"event"}
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Initializing in /home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Auto package restore: False
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Update workspace context
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Update project /home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Add project /home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp/project.json => 1ab361c7-ef0a-46cf-9d9e-dc6a791377d5
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem] Resolving projects references
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem]   Processing [ProjectState] hwapp/.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem]     Added 73 and removed 0 file references
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem]     Added 1 and removed 0 documents.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp#MSBuild] No solution files found in '/home/dany/Documents/VisualCodeProjects/hwapp'
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Configuration finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on a Ubuntu 16.10 machine with .NET Core 1.1 (from official Microsoft site www.microsoft.com/net/core) and Visual Studio Code > = 1.7.0

Installing the newest C# extension (1.6-beta3) helped.
See:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-Beta-Releases

executing 'dotnet --info':
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  16.10
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.16.10-x64